# Is there a microphone that works with Mindstorms EV3?

Tags: ev3, programming, ev3dev

I'm planning to program my EV3 robot to do voice chat over VOIP using ev3dev and a Debian program. Is this possible? Are there microphones known to work with EV3, and has anyone had experience using them?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, there isn't much info yet.

**Current options for audio are:**

- USB Sound Card
- BlueZ 4/Pulseaudio 4 (BlueZ 5/Pulseaudio 5 supports
  A2DP only)

The number of devices that have been tested and documented is extremely limited, but at least one has been confirmed to work. The non-bluetooth solutions that have been tested successfully are the following.

**Tested and confirmed adapter chipsets:**

- C-Media Electronics chipsets ([Example](http://www.buyincoins.com/item/16812.html))

**Tested and confirmed microphones:**

- Logitech C170 webcam built-in microphone

[More info in this github issue for ev3dev](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/185)

Answer (score 4):

There is a (new?) LEGO brand [sound sensor](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Sound-Sensor-9845) (9845) for $35 on the LEGO store. I don't know if it's suitable for your particular application but sounds plausible.

> Using the NXT Brick (sold separately), the Sound Sensor allows your LEGO® MINDSTORMS® NXT robot to hear! The Sound Sensor is able to measure noise levels in both dB (decibels) and dBA (frequencies around 3–6 kHz where the human ear is most sensitive).
>
> - Includes 1 Sound Sensor.
> - Does not include connector cable.
> - This is the individual component, and does not include the NXT Intelligent Brick, software or any accessories. It requires the complete LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT set (#8527 or #8547) for use.

Comment: That sensor is likely designed to measure the magnitude of noise, like clapping, but not provide access to an audio stream as desired above.

Comment: ok, understood. but maybe it can be adapted. it would come down to the details of the interface & driver etc.

Comment: **note, the web site/ link now says this product is discontinued with no further info** :(

Answer (score 3):

Copied from [Github](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev/issues/76):

I haven't heard of anyone using a microphone yet, but you have a couple of options. 1) a USB sound card/microphone or 2) Bluetooth headset/hands-free device.

The built-in speaker uses an alsa sound driver, so theoretically, it should work with any linux program.

If you are looking at purchasing something USB, make sure it does not require USB 2.0. The USB port on the EV3 is USB 1.1 only.